# How to setup a JMX Notification Listener?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jmx

This is a follow-up of [How to stop message processing before undeploying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792016/how-to-stop-message-processing-before-undeploying)

I want to configure a JMX Notification Listener for undeployment events, but I don't know how to set the mbean name correctly. We are currently using JBoss 4.2.3. The following attempt won't trigger any notification.

```
<mbean code="jboss.example.NotificationListener" 
        name="jboss.example:name=NotificationListener">
    <attribute name="SubscriptionList">
        <subscription-list>
            <mbean name="jboss.j2ee:service=EjbModule,type=jmx.attribute.change">
            </mbean>
            <notification type="JBOSS_MONITOR_NOTIFICATION"></notification>
        </subscription-list>
    </attribute>
</mbean>
```

Here is a list of all notification events, which pop up on undeployment:

```
2011-05-05 09:06:09,020 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb.EJBDeployer] Undeploying: file:/home/.../projects/jboss-server/local/server/dorun/tmp/deploy/tmp2721970726140354007mdb-simple.ear-contents/simple-mdb-ejb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2011-05-05 09:06:09,022 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification[source=jboss.j2ee:service=EjbModule,module=simple-mdb-ejb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar][type=jmx.attribute.change][message=EjbModule stopping], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:10,032 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification[source=jboss.j2ee:jndiName=local/SimpleMessageEJB@30208588,service=EJB][type=jmx.attribute.change][message=MessageDrivenContainer stopping], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:11,050 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification[source=jboss.j2ee:service=EJB,plugin=invoker,binding=message-driven-bean,jndiName=local/SimpleMessageEJB@30208588][type=jmx.attribute.change][message=JMSContainerInvoker stopping], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:12,061 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.Notification[source=jboss.j2ee:service=EJB,plugin=invoker,binding=message-driven-bean,jndiName=local/SimpleMessageEJB@30208588][type=org.jboss.ejb.plugins.jms.DISCONNECTING][message=], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:13,110 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.Notification[source=jboss.j2ee:service=EJB,plugin=invoker,binding=message-driven-bean,jndiName=local/SimpleMessageEJB@30208588][type=org.jboss.ejb.plugins.jms.DISCONNECTED][message=], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:14,119 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification[source=jboss.j2ee:service=EJB,plugin=invoker,binding=message-driven-bean,jndiName=local/SimpleMessageEJB@30208588][type=jmx.attribute.change][message=JMSContainerInvoker stopped], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:15,128 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.Notification[source=jboss.system:service=ServiceController][type=org.jboss.system.ServiceMBean.stop][message=], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:16,138 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification[source=jboss.j2ee:service=EJB,plugin=pool,jndiName=local/SimpleMessageEJB@30208588][type=jmx.attribute.change][message=MessageDrivenInstancePool stopping], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:17,148 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification[source=jboss.j2ee:service=EJB,plugin=pool,jndiName=local/SimpleMessageEJB@30208588][type=jmx.attribute.change][message=MessageDrivenInstancePool stopped], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:18,157 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.Notification[source=jboss.system:service=ServiceController][type=org.jboss.system.ServiceMBean.stop][message=], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:19,166 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification[source=jboss.j2ee:jndiName=local/SimpleMessageEJB@30208588,service=EJB][type=jmx.attribute.change][message=MessageDrivenContainer stopped], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:20,175 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.Notification[source=jboss.system:service=ServiceController][type=org.jboss.system.ServiceMBean.stop][message=], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:21,184 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification[source=jboss.j2ee:service=EjbModule,module=simple-mdb-ejb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar][type=jmx.attribute.change][message=EjbModule stopped], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:22,193 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.Notification[source=jboss.system:service=ServiceController][type=org.jboss.system.ServiceMBean.stop][message=], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:23,202 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.Notification[source=jboss.ejb:service=EJBDeployer][type=org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployer.stop][message=], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:24,211 INFO  [org.jboss.deployment.ClientDeployer] Removing client ENC from: SimpleMessageClient
2011-05-05 09:06:24,212 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.Notification[source=jboss.j2ee:service=ClientDeployer][type=org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployer.stop][message=], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:25,221 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.Notification[source=jboss.management.local:ServiceModule=simple-mdb-sar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.sar,name=jboss.example%3aname%3dNotificationListener,J2EEServer=Local,J2EEApplication=null,j2eeType=MBean][type=j2ee.state.stopping][message=State changed], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:26,229 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification[source=jboss.example:name=NotificationListener][type=jmx.attribute.change][message=NotificationListener stopping], handback: null
2011-05-05 09:06:27,236 INFO  [STDOUT] Stop NotificationListener.
```

I thought it would be best to catch the very first event, so I want to catch:

```
2011-05-05 09:06:09,022 INFO  [STDOUT] Got notification: javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification[source=jboss.j2ee:service=EjbModule,module=simple-mdb-ejb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar][type=jmx.attribute.change][message=EjbModule stopping], handback: null
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Chris;

Are you using EJB 2.x ? I ask because the EJB 2.x MDB management interface is a little trickier than it is for EJB 3 because it contains a serial number in the object name and when I saw this in your log extract, it made me think you were in EJB 2:   jndiName=local/SimpleMessageEJB@30208588

Comment: Oh, I used an example project which I found on the net. I'll refactor it. In real projects we're using EJB3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the example JBoss NotificationListener and assuming an EJB3 MDB deploymentas follows:

- **EAR**: myear.ear
- **JAR**: myjar.jar
- **MDB Name**: MyMDB

the deployment descriptor for the listener MBean would be like this:

```
  <server>
    <mbean code="jboss.example.NotificationListener"
           name="jboss.example:name=NotificationListener">
      <attribute name="SubscriptionList">      
        <subscription-list>
          <mbean name="jboss.j2ee:ear=myear.ear,jar=myjar.jar,service=EJB3,name=MyMDB" handback="MyMDB">
            <notification type="jmx.attribute.change">
          </mbean>
        </subscription-list>
      </attribute>
    </mbean>
  </server>
```

If you were to simply log the **toString** of the notification when stopping the MDB, it would look something like this:

**State 3 (Started) --> State 1 (Stopping)**

```
    NOTIFICATION:<javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification@60de8209
attributeName=State attributeType=java.lang.Integer **oldValue=3 newValue=1
type=jmx.attribute.change** sequenceNumber=7 timeStamp=1305033720266 userData=null
message=MdbDelegateWrapper stopping 
source=jboss.j2ee:ear=myear.ear,jar=myear.jar,name=MyMDB,service=EJB3 
source=jboss.j2ee:ear=myear.ear,jar=myear.jar,name=MyMDB,service=EJB3>
```

**State 1 (Stopping) --> State 0 (Stopped)**

```
NOTIFICATION:<javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification@296e41ab attributeName=State
attributeType=java.lang.Integer **oldValue=1 newValue=0 type=jmx.attribute.change**
sequenceNumber=8 timeStamp=1305033720320 userData=null 
message=MdbDelegateWrapper stopped 
source=jboss.j2ee:ear=myear.ear,jar=myear.jar,name=MyMDB,service=EJB3 
source=jboss.j2ee:ear=myear.ear,jar=myear.jar,name=MyMDB,service=EJB3>
```

Comment: Thank you. Where did you get your knowledge from? I searched it a few hours, but I didn't find an unique explanation of the subscription-list element.